# My redirect isn't working well with IPInfo.io

Tags: javascript, json, api

I need help with redirect to subdomains. With IPinfo I get country of visitor then i redirect him to one of my subdomains and i need this look like ua.mysite or kz.mysite or ru.mysite
I tried `window.location.href =  data.country + 'mysite'` but this didn't work. Hope you can help me! :)

````
  // Let's check if we have the value in localstorage
  if (localStorage.getItem('country') == 'RU') {
    // Already have the value in localStorage no need to make call to IPinfo
     window.location.hostname = 'ru.mysite.tech'
  } else if(localStorage.getItem('country') == 'KZ') {
    // Already have the value in localStorage no need to make call to IPinfo
     window.location.hostname = 'kz.mysite.tech'
  } else if(localStorage.getItem('country') == 'UA') {
    // Already have the value in localStorage no need to make call to IPinfo
     window.location.hostname = 'ua.mysite.tech'
  }

  else{
    // No cached data, let's get it from IPinfo
    fetch('https://ipinfo.io/json?<MyToken>')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if(data.country == 'UA'){
          localStorage.setItem('ipinfo', data.country)
          window.location.hostname = 'ua.mysite.tech'
        }
        else if(data.country == 'KZ'){
          localStorage.setItem('ipinfo', data.country)
          window.location.hostname = 'kz.mysite.tech'
        }
        else {
          localStorage.setItem('ipinfo', data.country)
          window.location.hostname = 'ru.mysite.tech'
        }
    })
  }
}```
````

Comment: It returns empty http page

Answer (score 0):

Updates to `window.location.hostname` don't cause redirect.

You should update `window.location` directly like this (note the "https:/"):

```
if (localStorage.getItem('country') == 'RU') {
  // Already have the value in localStorage no need to make call to IPinfo
   window.location = 'https://ru.mysite.tech'
}
```

Comment: thank for answer, i tried this. It links me to mysite.tech/ru.mysite.tech. I need ru.mysite.tech

Comment: @bbjhx you missed `https://`. Please read my example carefully

Comment: So thats work only with https not with http? I tried with http. Now i fixed it with document.location()

Comment: @bbjhx no matter http or https. You just need to write full address with schema, not only domain name.